# Nested view model structure causing error in a ko.computed

Tags: javascript, mvvm, knockout.js

I´m having a javascript viewModel that is initiated with a "model" dataset containing a list of projects. Since I want to switch between projects from my page I collect all other data in a subscription. The "selectedProject" defines the selected value from a `<select>`.
I trigger the subscription for the first time by initiating selectedProject to the first element in the Projects-array.

Somehow I get the error message

```
TypeError: batch is undefined
return item.parentID === batch.parentID; 
^
```

and I cannot understand why.

This is my code:

```
ViewModel = function (model)  {
    var self = this;

    self.selectedProject = ko.observable();
    self.selectedText = ko.observable();
    self.Textbatches = ko.observableArray();

    self.Projects = ko.observableArray(
        ko.utils.arrayMap(model, function (item) {
            return new Project(item);
        }));

    self.selectedProject.subscribe(function (project) { 

        /* ...some code... */ 

        $.getJSON("myService/GetTextbatchesFromDB", "projectID=" + project.projectID,
            function (allData) {
               var mappedTextbatches = $.map(allData, function (item) {
                    return new Textbatch(item);
               });
               self.Textbatches(mappedTextbatches);

               self.selectedText(self.Textbatches()[0]);

            }
         ); // End of $.getJSON

        /* ...some more code... */
    }

    self.selectedProject(self.Projects()[0]);  


    self.parentIDFilteredTextbatches = ko.computed(function () {
        var batch = self.selectedText();
        return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.Textbatches(), function (item) {
            return item.parentID === batch.parentID;   /* ERROR ON THIS LINE */
        });
   });
}
```

And in the < HTML>:

```
<script>

    // some code getting "model from the db...

    var viewModel = new ViewModel(model);
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
</script>
```

I have found that if I move the "self.parentIDFilteredTextbatches = ko.computed()"-functon inside the self.selectedProject.subscribe-function after the initialisation of self.selectedText() it will work when the page is first loaded.

However, I´m not to fond of such an view model structure (maybe I´ll get used to it) and worse, I get the same error when selecting a new project (i.e. selectedProject.subscription is triggered).

Comment: ok, thanks anyway. Let me know if you figure something out. I´m quite fresh to this MVVM/javascript thing, so there might be I´m lacking some basic understanding.

Comment: My suspicion is with `var mappedTextbatches` you aren't doing anything with that local variable. Is there another declaration of `mappedTextbatches` that you've excluded in the code redactions?

Comment: I have no problems with the mappedTextbatches. The Textbatches-array gets values after the selectedProject.subscribe is run.

Comment: the problem is getjson is async

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "scope" issue is a 2 part problem that isn't an actual problem.

- The original provided example is missing some closure braces for `$.getJSON`.
- The positioning on the closure of `$.map` looks like those of `$.getJSON`  and visually indicates a scoping problem that doesn't actually exist.

The problem is `selectedText` has no dependency on `TextBatches` and is manually set to be `undefined` since the subscription has yet (*synchronicity*) to populate `TextBatches`. Once the subscription forces an evaluation of the computed `selectedText` still has an `undefined` and now `TextBatches` has actual data which then causes the `arrayFilter` callback to execute.

The console statements within [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/origineil/m073t1jz/) illustrate the sequence of events in the code.

Another [example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/origineil/m073t1jz/4/).

Answer (score 2):

Your problem has to do with the scope of the "mappedTextbatches" variable. There may also be a slight syntax error.

The view model's `Textbatches` property does not have access to the `mappedTextbatches` variable due to the latter's scope. Later on when you try to access the `parentID` property of `Textbatches[0]` (as a local variable set from the `selectedText` property), you get the undefined error because `Textbatches` was never actually set.

See this jsFiddle for a further explanation and example: http://jsfiddle.net/0p5fftcc/

```
/* Demonstrates a similar behavior to 
 * your current view model.
 */
var currentViewModel = function () {

var self = this;

self.personName = ko.observable('Bob');
self.personAge = ko.observable(10);
self.hasPersonNameChanged = ko.observable(false);

self.personName.subscribe(function (newValue) {
    self.hasPersonNameChanged(true);

    (function fakeGetJSON() {
        /* The local age variable is within the
         * function closure, so personAge cannot
         * get access to it.
         */
        var localAge = 20;
    })();

    self.personAge(localAge);
});
};
```

I can't test this to make sure, but I'm guessing if you change your code to the following, you should no longer receive the error.

```
var mappedTextbatches = $.getJSON("myService/GetTextbatchesFromDB", "projectID=" + project.projectID, function (allData) {
    return $.map(allData, function (item) {
        return new Textbatch(item);
    });
});
```

**Edit to reflect new code in the post**

Go ahead and check for `selectedText` having a value before evaluating. See below.

```
    self.parentIDFilteredTextbatches = ko.computed(function () {

        if (self.selectedText() !== undefined) {
            var batch = self.selectedText();
            return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.Textbatches(), function (item) {
                return item.parentID === batch.parentID;   /* ERROR ON THIS LINE */
            });
        }

        return;
    });
```

Although I can't determine how with the information provided, I'm going to assume `self.selectedText` can be interacted with on the client. Assuming this but without knowing more, a less than desirable, albeit quick, fix to your issue would be to change the `Textbatches` property declaration to the following at the top of your view model. This will slow down the notification to the computed function which holds subscriptions to both `Textbatches` and `selectedText`, hopefully allowing enough time for `selectedText` to be set.

```
self.Textbatches = ko.observableArray().extend({ rateLimit: 500 });
```

This will also circumvent an issue you'll have later whereby there is a mismatch between the new `Textbatches` and the old `selectedText` on subsequent client updates that you would get if you just implemented the check for `undefined`.

A comprehensive solution would probably involve redesigning your data structure with regards to what each object holds, but I can't tell from your post exactly what each property is supposed to represent.

Comment: No problem! Maybe if I explain it another way it will make sense. The biggest thing is you need to move your mappedTextbatches to the same level as where you use it to set self.Textbatches. 

Right now it is inside your getJson function, so self.Textbatches doesn't have access to it. When you go ahead and set self.Textbatches to it anyways, it says, "Okay, set this to undefined."

Later, when you try to access the nested property, it says, "Hey, this object itself is undefined. I can't access a property within undefined."

Comment: As Origineil pointed out my example lacked the ending parenthesis of the $getJSON. In my code "self.Textbatches(mappedTextbatches);" is done in the callback of the $.getJSON, thus I guess this is not the problem?

Comment: I see you've changed your code above, but it is still suffering from the same issue. I think if you read through the jsFiddle you will be able to understand. Here's another reference that might help (look at how they explain access to the carName variable): http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp

Comment: chrisjsherm self.Textbatches(mappedtextbatches) is set inside the $.getJSON call. It does get the right data. My trouble is the self.selectedText().

Comment: You also have another syntax error further down. As an aside, consider using a JavaScript linter to help catch these easy to miss errors. It will not only help you, but also us in not having to guess where you intended to create things like closures.

Comment: I see what Origineil is saying, but his example is also different from what I assume you intended, because he had to guess about another closure where you have an error. Based on your update, I think you probably intend to have "self.selectedText(self.Textbatches()[0]);" at the same level as where you set "self.Textbatches". The issue becomes you have a subscription in your computed that is not set, because the computed function evaluates when "self.Textbatches" is set, which is what Origineil is trying to point out. KnockoutJS docs: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html

Comment: Without knowing more about how your properties are being used on the client, a less than desirable but quick way to solve your issue would be to set Textbatches to the following when declaring it: self.Textbatches = ko.observableArray().extend({ rateLimit: 500 }); See my edit above for more info.

Comment: you might have a point, but I don´t get it. I run Firebug on my code. I have switch the data collection to a synchronous AJAX (async: false). I have the following to lines just after each other:  self.Textbatches = ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(batches, function (item) {return new Textbatch(item);}));
self.selectedText(self.Textbatches()[0]); 
I step through in the debugger and it tells me self.Textbatches()[0] holds an object with textbatchId=9 and still after stepping over line2 above self.selectedText() is undefined even though (to me) they are clearly in the same context.

Answer (score 0):

Chris gave the right answer. More specifically this:

```
$.getJSON("myService/GetTextbatchesFromDB", "projectID=" + project.projectID,
    function (allData) {
        var mappedTextbatches = $.map(allData, function (item) {
            return new Textbatch(item);
});
self.Textbatches(mappedTextbatches);
```

Should be this

```
var mappedTextbatches;
$.getJSON("myService/GetTextbatchesFromDB", "projectID=" + project.projectID,
    function (allData) {
        mappedTextbatches = $.map(allData, function (item) {
            return new Textbatch(item);
});
self.Textbatches(mappedTextbatches);
```

Comment: make sure T is capitalized is return new Textbatch

Comment: It is. The error remains in "return item.parentID === batch.parentID;"